# SXA Item Queries vs Search Scope

Tags: sxa

I want to know the best practice in using Item Queries and Search scope.

When should i use Item queries and when to use search scope as both of them is used in building queries

Any advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two features are similar in that they make use of the `Query Builder` field type, and are used in searching for items by SXA.

---

**Item Queries** is used by list components such as the following:

- Archive
- Link List
- Page List
- Tags
- ...

You can create custom queries under *Settings > Item Queries*, which will be bundled up with queries that come OOTB. You can also code a custom one like [here](https://www.sitecorenutsbolts.net/2018/03/16/Sitecore-SXA-Custom-PageList-data-sources/) from Richard Seal.

On the Page List you can see the query configured using the *Source Type* parameter.
[image]

---

**Search Scope** is used by other search enabled components which all get wired together using a common search signature. You can scope search in the following ways:

- Globally for the tenant on the *Settings* item because it inherits from the *_Search Criteria* template.
- Locally for the page because it inherits from *_Page Search Scope*.
- At a component level on the *Search Results* component.

On the Search Results component you can see the scope configured using the Search Scope parameter.

[image]

On the page you can configure the scope under the Search Criteria section.

[image]

On the Settings item you can configure the scope under Search Criteria section.

[image]

---

**Note:** Something I am not clear on is whether the **Item Queries** acknowledge the scope defined under Settings or on the page.